# UIModalPresentationCustom style changes view width on rotation

Tags: ios, uimodalpresentationstyle, uimodalpresentationcustom

I have a modal I am presenting using UIModalPresentationCustom. I have the "to" view controller's view frame set to 300 pixels wide in the animateTransition method. When I present the modal, the width is fine, but when I rotate the screen, the width changes. Is there a property or delegate method I can latch onto that I can override the modified width?